The PUT method is not supported for route posts/2e1585f6-1b1a-4bd9-9bb1-3138f45fc9bd/edit. Supported methods: GET, HEAD
I am using resource controller for posts - used method spoofing for PUT and trying to update but getting this error. ( This is happening when i am submitting the form to update )
Even i am putting GET or HEAD method - it's not working and giving the same error.
This is my routes in web.php
    // Post Routes
    Route::resource('/posts', PostController::class);

This is my edit form
<form
    method="POST"
    action="{{ route('posts.update', $postDetail->uuid) }}"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    class="bg-white border-2 border-black rounded-lg shadow mx-auto max-w-none px-4 py-5 sm:px-6 space-y-3">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <!-- Create Post Card Top -->
    <div>
        <div class="flex items-start /space-x-3/">
            <!-- User Avatar -->
            <div class="flex-shrink-0">
                <img
                    class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full object-cover"
                    src="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/831997"
                    alt="Ahmed Shamim" />
            </div>

            <!-- /User Avatar -->

            <!-- Content -->
            <div class="text-gray-700 font-normal w-full">
                <textarea
                    class="block w-full p-2 pt-2 text-gray-900 rounded-lg border-none outline-none focus:ring-0 focus:ring-offset-0"
                    name="editedVersionOfThePost"
                    rows="8">{{ old('editedVersionOfThePost') }}</textarea>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Create Post Card Bottom -->
    <div>
        <!-- Card Bottom Action Buttons -->
        <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
            <div class="flex gap-4 text-gray-600">
                <!-- Upload Picture Button -->
                <div>
                    <input
                        type="file"
                        name="picture"
                        id="picture"
                        class="hidden" />

                    <label
                        for="picture"
                        class="-m-2 flex gap-2 text-xs items-center rounded-full p-2 text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800 cursor-pointer">
                        <span class="sr-only">Picture</span>
                        <img src="{{ asset('icons/image.svg') }}" alt="">
                    </label>
                </div>

                <!-- /Upload Picture Button -->

                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="-m-2 flex gap-2 text-xs items-center rounded-full p-2 text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800">
                    <span class="sr-only">GIF</span>
                    <img src="{{ asset('icons/gif.svg') }}" alt="">
                </button>

                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="-m-2 flex gap-2 text-xs items-center rounded-full p-2 text-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800">
                    <span class="sr-only">Emoji</span>
                    <img src="{{ asset('icons/emoji_smile.svg') }}" alt="">
                </button>

            </div>

            <div>
                <!-- Post Button -->
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    class="-m-2 flex gap-2 text-xs items-center rounded-full px-4 py-2 font-semibold bg-gray-800 hover:bg-black text-white">
                    Update
                </button>
                <!-- /Post Button -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Card Bottom Action Buttons -->
    </div>
    <!-- /Create Post Card Bottom -->
</form>

As per the error message - I tried with GET and HEAD method, still getting the same issue.

I don't think your error is on this form, but somewhere you are trying to perform a put request to posts.edit instead of posts.update. posts.edit will only return the edit form and is always a GET route.

When looking at the page source, what is the generated form action? Also, is there perhaps some kind of redirect in your controller update function?

Thanks guys, for responding, i got the solution - Actually it's my mistake.
I have a separate update.blade.php but i was editing another file.
